# How do I dynamically change the path_to()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, send

I currently have three methods which I want to collapse into one:

```
  def send_email(contact,email)

  end

  def make_call(contact, call)
    return link_to "Call", new_contact_call_path(:contact => contact, :call => call, :status => 'called')
  end

  def make_letter(contact, letter)
    return link_to "Letter", new_contact_letter_path(:contact => contact, :letter => letter, :status => 'mailed')
  end
```

I want to collapse the three into one so that I can just pass the Model as one of the parameters and it will still correctly create the path_to.  I am trying to do this with the following, but stuck:

```
  def do_event(contact, call_or_email_or_letter)
    model_name = call_or_email_or_letter.class.name.tableize.singularize
   link_to "#{model_name.camelize}", new_contact_#{model_name}_path(contact, call_or_email_or_letter)" 
  end
```

Thanks to the answers here, I have tried the following, which gets me closer:

```
link_to( "#{model_name.camelize}", send("new_contact_#{model_name}_path", 
                                        :contact => contact, 
                                        :status => "done",
                                        :model_name => model_name) )
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to past the #{model_name} when it is an :attribute and then send the value of model_name, not as a string, but referring the object.

**I got this to work:** -- giving points to Kadada because he got me in the right direction :)

```
  def do_event(contact, call_or_email_or_letter) 
    model_name = call_or_email_or_letter.class.name.tableize.singularize 
    link_to( "#{model_name.camelize}", send("new_contact_#{model_name}_path", 
                                            :contact => contact, 
                                            :status => 'done',
                                            :"#{model_name}" => call_or_email_or_letter ) )                                       
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def do_event(contact, call_or_email_or_letter)
  model_name = call_or_email_or_letter.class.name.tableize.singularize
  link_to( "#{model_name.camelize}", send("new_contact_#{model_name}_path", 
                 contact, call_or_email_or_letter) )
end
```

Comment: The "hand coded way" I create the new path is this: new_contact_letter_path(:contact => contact, :letter => letter, :status => 'mailed') I looked up "send" to understand how this works...can you help?

Comment: I updated my question to include what I"ve tried based on your suggestions...getting close except for the model_name....thanks!  You've been so helpful and great.

Comment: The `send` method is a method on the Object class.

Comment: so how would I make this work, I don't think I could get your version to work...I can try again...

Comment: got it to work, with a modification, but your help made the difference so awarded it to you :)