# Path from string with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I need a good way to create a set of Rails 3 paths from an array, in the `link_to` helper.

I have:

```
TITLES = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
TITLES.each do |t|
  = link_to t, (.....path....)
```

This way i need to construct a set of paths:

```
foo_super_users_path(user)
bar_super_users_path(user)
baz_super_users_path(user)
```

As you can see, i need to add same prefix **_super_users** for every single path, and pass **user** object. As the final result, i need something like:

```
link_to t, foo_super_users_path(user)
link_to t, bar_super_users_path(user)
link_to t, baz_super_users_path(user)
```

Your suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: This maybe similar to what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792946/how-do-i-dynamically-change-the-path-to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
TITLES.each do |t|
  = link_to t, eval("#{t}_super_users_path(user)")
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using `eval` ever, just google it. lots of bad results can happen

Answer (score 9):

Instead eval use public_send

```
TITLES.each do |t|
  = link_to t, public_send("#{t}_super_users_path", user)
```

Comment: public_send("#{t}_super_users_path",user)